# $m_{x_1x_2}\leq m_{x_2x_3}\Rightarrow f$ is convex.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $J \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ an interval. If $f:J \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall{x_1,x_2,x_3 \in J}$

$m_{x_1x_2}\leq m_{x_2x_3}\Rightarrow f$ is convex.

Where   $m_{x_1x_2}=\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}$.

Please help for this exercise.

Comment: Welcome to SEM. I would like to suggest you, in order to get the best benefit of your question , please state what did you try , how is your  point of view towards the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x,y \in J$. Required to show $ \forall  \lambda  \in ]0,1[ $,  $$f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y). $$
let  $z=\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y$, then we have (by hypothesis)
$$\frac{f(z)-f(y)}{z-y} \leq \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}  $$
On the other hand, 
$$ \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}  \geq\frac{f(z)-f(y)}{z-y} =\frac{ f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y) -  f(y) }{ \lambda x+(1-\lambda)y -y} =\frac{ f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y) -  f(y) }{ \lambda (x-y) }  $$
so $$ f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y) -  f(y) \leq \lambda f(x) -\lambda f(y)  $$
Thus $$ f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)  \leq \lambda f(x)+(1 -\lambda )f(y)  $$